# java cannot return my variable from inherated class to super class

Tags: java

I have a superclass and an inherited class that's inheriting a variable called "answer"... I modify that variable in my inherted class but when i try to display it back in my super class it does not work! tried multiple ways, now i am losing my mind!

```
  class RightTriangle{
  public double answer;

  public RightTriangle(){} ;

  public double getAnswer(){return answer;} 

  public double returnAnswer(){
     this.answer = answer;
     return answer;
  }
  public String toString(){
     return ("Answer: " + answer);
  }

 }

class sideAngle extends RightTriangle{
  public double nintyDegree = 90;
  private double sideA;
  private double angleB;
  private double answerUpdate;

  public sideAngle(double sideA, double angleB){ 
     this.sideA = sideA;
     this.angleB = angleB; 
  }

  public void solveEquation(){
     angleB = Math.toRadians(angleB);
     answerUpdate = Math.tan(angleB);
     answer = sideA * answerUpdate;
     System.out.println(answer);
  }  
 }
```

I get a 0, instead of lets say a number that prints out right in my testing statement in solve Equation constructor !

also here is how I called/initialized them in my main(don't think i called wrong!).

```
sideAngle angleSide = new sideAngle(firstNum, secondNum);
angleSide.solveEquation();
RightTriangle getAnswer = new RightTriangle();
System.out.println(getAnswer.toString()); <<<<<<<<
```

prints out a 0 !

Comment: That does not even compile. Please provide a https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve and the inputs that show the problem.

Comment: Yeah im really sorry I had to modify it before I post it here but forgot took out some important stuff! I just added  the "Answer" in the String so it sees the  answer as string, it should compile, still getting back a 0. lets say input is 700 and 55 or any number you want, i just want it to return something and print out but in the super class!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The two instance that you created, `getAnswer` and `angleSide` are two completely different objects. They do not interact in any way. In your case, `angleSide` calculated the answer, but there is no way, a new instance, `getAnswer` will know that.

Instead, I think what you want to do is to call `toString()` directly on the `angleSide` object. Since `sideAngle` is a child of `RightTriangle`, all instances of `sideAngle` knows about this `toString()` implementation. So calling `angleSide.toString()` will return you the answer.

Comment: THANK YOU!.... I have written a program before and got this exact same error and fixed it....but I keep forgetting that the inherited classes have access to the super class's toString method... im stupid!... make this a lesson for everyone.